# Lambda expression too complex for editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, lambda

Within my view, I have a line of code that renders an editor template.

However, it returns the error:

**Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

This seems like the most elegant way to achieve what I want but I realise the lambda expression in my view is too complex for the editor template.

Can anybody suggest how to make this work or advise me of a better way?

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Approvers.Where(a => a.ApprovalCount > 0))
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.AssignedApproverData

<div class="span3">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeID)    
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Assigned)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)
    </label>
</div>
```

**Editor Template ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class AssignedApproverData
    {
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public bool Assigned { get; set; }
        public int ApprovalCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class ChangeRequestViewModel
    {
        public virtual ICollection<AssignedApproverData> Approvers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all: you cannot use complex lambda expressions with strongly typed helpers. Only property access and indexer access expressions are supported.

> Can anybody suggest how to make this work or advise me of a better way?

By using a view model of course.

So go ahead and define a property on your view model that you could use in your view instead of writing such code in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AcceptedApprovers)
```

and you will have the corresponding property on your view model:

```
public class ChangeRequestViewModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<AssignedApproverData> AcceptedApprovers { get; set; }
}
```

and in your controller action that is rendering this view you will populate this property from your domain model:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var domainModel = ... fetch your domain model from your repository as usual
    var viewModel = new ChangeRequestViewModel();
    viewModel.AcceptedApprovers = domainModel.Approvers.Where(a => a.ApprovalCount > 0);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Obviously the view model will contain only the information necessary by the view, not more, not less.